# Appium launching on real device but chrome hangs

Tags: c#, android, automation, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running Appium `1.6.1` on Windows 10, and I'm trying to automate Chrome on a real device (in this instance a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android `7.0`). I'm using `C#` and visual studio. My code looks like the below:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;


namespace MobileBrowserTesting{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1{

    AppiumDriver<IWebElement> Driver;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1(){

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.SetCapability("deviceName", "hero2lteskt");
        caps.SetCapability("udid", "ce11160b3889d43005"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.SetCapability("browserName", "Chrome");

        //Launch the Android driver
        Driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.3:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        string url = Driver.Url;
        bool viewable = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("q")).Displayed;


    }
  }
}
```

Chrome launches, however it simply sits at "data;" with a blank screen and doesn't progress to the website. The last step in the Appium view is:

```
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST 
http://127.0.0.1:8001/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities": 
{"chromeOptions": 
{"androidPackage": "com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"ce11160b3889d43005"}}}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - -
```

And visual studio times out with the error message:

```
Message: Test method MobileBrowserTesting.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw 
exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.3:4723/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
```

After a while Appium times out with:

```
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Failed to start 
Chromedriver session: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing 
the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device ce11160b3889d43005 is 
already in use
```

Appium is launched in admin mode, with "Allow session override" ticked under Advanced.
The chromedriver being used is the latest one (`2.39`) and the version of chrome on the device is `66.0.3359.158` so it should be compatible.

Any ideas why it seems to hang/not interact with Chrome?

Cheers in advance